# Does TensorFlow optimizer minimize API implemented mini-batch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, training-data, mini-batch

Does Tensorflow [minimize](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/GradientDescentOptimizer) API for, say GradientDescentOptimizer implement mini-batch already when we feed the input tensor with a minibatch size of data?

I was reading this [bolg](http://deeplearnphysics.org/Blog/minibatch.html) which indicated that the minibatch is not implemented in the `minimize` method, we have to do `compute_gradients` first and then accumulate the gradients, finally do the `apply_gradients` to finish the minibatch training.

```
def train_standard(opt_type, learning_rate, image_set):
# Arrays for logging accuracy and loss
acc_log = np.zeros(len(image_set))
loss_log = np.zeros(len(image_set))
# Create optimizer
opt = opt_type(learning_rate)
#
# no-minibatch (standard, simple) operation
#
minimize = opt.minimize(loss)
# Create session to execute ops
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
# Necessary initializations
tf.set_random_seed(1234)
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
# Train loop
for i, batch in enumerate(image_set):
    sess.run(minimize, feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

    acc_log[i] = sess.run(accuracy, 
                          feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels})
    loss_log[i] = sess.run(loss, 
                           feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels})

return acc_log, loss_log
```

However, when I do the experiments, I found that two approaches generate similar results. I wonder if the `minimize` method will do the minibatch update if we `feed_dict` is a minibatch size matrix instead just one row of the training data.

Can anyone help me to clarify this question and correct me if I am wrong?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your definition of learning with minibatches. One way to do that is to simply sample a minibatch, perform a weight update (i.e., compute forward and backward pass), sample another minibatch, perform another weight update, and so on. This is easily done with `Optimizer.minimize()` when you just feed one minibatch at a time. AFAIK, this is the most commonly used method.

The post you're liking aims to do something else: compute the gradients on multiple minibatches (i.e. compute forward and backward pass, but don't change the weights), and then perform a single weight update using all of the the accumulated gradients. That is of course different, and more work to implement (as shown in the post).

Comment: Thanks for answering, I think my definition will be the first one you mentioned. So according to your answer, if we `sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={input_tf: batch_data})` where `train_op` is from `Optimizer.minimize()` and `batch_data` is a minbatch size of data sample then the update will be minibatch. In another word, if we want to do an iterative update we have to feed one row of training data each iteration. Is my understanding of your answer right?

Comment: Yes, just feed a single minibatch into `sess.run()`, that's all.